# Element is not workable code is 100% correct

Tags: jquery, html, element

I have 2 images (#werkwijze & #werkwijzehover) styled and positioned at the same place in my document. Werkwijzehover has `display: none`, I have written code in jQuery so that when #werkwijze is hovered over it should get display: Hidden and #werkwijzehover should get display: Block.

I am 99.9% sure my code is correct. Also I have link tags around these elements yet I am not able to click them. Anybody know what is going on here?

```js
$('#werkwijze').hover(function() {
  $('#werkwijze').css(
    'display', 'none');

  $('#werkwijzehover').css(
    'display', 'block');

});

$('#werkwijzehover').mouseout(function() {
  $('#werkwijzehover').css(
    'display', 'none');

  $('#werkwijze').css(
    'display', 'block');
});
```

```css
#wrapperhome10 {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
#werkwijze {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 35%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  display: block;
}
#werkwijzehover {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 35%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapperhome10">
  <a>
    <img id="werkwijze" src="images/werkwijze.png" />
  </a>
  <a>
    <img id="werkwijzehover" src="images/werkwijzehover.png" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: `<a>` tags are not clickable if they don't have an `href` or a bound event.

Comment: `99.9% != 100%`

Comment: yeah besides of that the hover should work no?

Comment: @Pieter I just ran your code snippet, replacing the images so that I could actually see them, and it works fine. What about it is not working for you? Are you getting any console errors (F12 in browser) when running the page?

Comment: only 1 error but is does not have anything to do with the script I am having issues with, I have used the same code on other elements and it works fine in the same code from the same script only these 2 don't work it's got me mindblown :p

Comment: Where did you include your js file?

Comment: pieterswebdesign.com/desktop/homepage.html I put the whole thing online It is in content -> wrapperhome6 -> wrapperhome10 that is where the elements are listed –

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working fine to me. Run this code-snippet below and see if it's working as you expect, or let me know in the comments below what is wrong here and I'll see how I can help further.

```js
$('#werkwijze').hover(function() {
  $('#werkwijze').css(
    'display', 'none');

  $('#werkwijzehover').css(
    'display', 'block');

});

$('#werkwijzehover').mouseout(function() {
  $('#werkwijzehover').css(
    'display', 'none');

  $('#werkwijze').css(
    'display', 'block');
});
```

```css
#wrapperhome10 {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
#werkwijze {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 35%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  display: block;
}
#werkwijzehover {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 35%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapperhome10">
  <a>
    <img id="werkwijze" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" />
  </a>
  <a>
    <img id="werkwijzehover" src="https://s1.yimg.com/rz/d/yahoo_en-US_f_p_bestfit_2x.png" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I works as is should in the snippet. It is very weird it is the exact same code as in my document but the element just doesn't seem to respond in my document :/

Comment: @Pieter Then the answer is that you're having an issue somewhere outside of the code you've supplied us. Is your jquery wrapped in `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`? I don't believe your listeners will work if not.

Comment: Where is your javascript? External? In the `<head>`? Put an `alert()` in your `hover` and see if it gets triggered.

Comment: it is wrapped in just that it isn't the Jquery if you ask me.

Comment: Well being that you're here asking for help, despite being 99% sure your code is right and not thinking it's the JQuery, we're going to have to take some basic debugging steps. Stick an `alert()` in your hover and let me know if it fires.

Comment: it is in the body at the bottom. And there are other elements in the same scripts which are getting targeted with the same code they work fine. I think it's something in the html because when i put <a> </a> tag around these elements it also is not clickable and yes I gave them an href this time over :p

Comment: If you have an `href` on the `<a>` and it is still not clickable, it sounds like you have an element overlapping/covering your image. This would explain why your `<a>` is not clickable and why your `hover` isn't triggering. I'd suggest doing an Inspect Element to find what is covering your stuff.

Comment: $('#werkwijze').hover(function()
 {
  $('#werkwijze').alert('Hello')

  $('#werkwijze').css(
   'display', 'none');

  $('#werkwijzehover').css(
   'display', 'block');

 });  Does not do anything

Comment: http://www.pieterswebdesign.com/desktop/homepage.html I put the whole thing online cause I can't find the overlapping element either :/ It is in content -> wrapperhome6 -> wrapperhome10 that is where the elements are listed

Comment: @Pieter Your div `wrapperhome11` is covering your button, as I expected. Additionally. remove the `alert()` from your hover jquery - You assigned it to an element which is improper syntax, but now that I feel the issue is solved, we don't need it anymore.